# Segmentation fault when splitting a memory block in C

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I'm currently recoding my own version of `malloc()`, I'm currently only using `sbrk()` and would like to implement a version with `mmap()` later on.

Here's the block metadata structure:

```c
typedef struct MV_BLOCK_S {
    uint32_t magic;
    struct MV_BLOCK_S *prev;
    uint64_t size;
    uint8_t state; // First bit: 0 = block free, 1 = block used, second bit: 0 = sbrk() 1 = mmap()
    void *data;
    struct MV_BLOCK_S *next;
} mv_block_t;
```

Some of the macros I use:

```c
#define MV_ALIGN(x) (((((x) - 1) >> 3) << 3) + 8)
#define MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE  MV_ALIGN(sizeof(mv_block_t))
#define MV_BLOCK_T_END_OFFSET MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE - sizeof(mv_block_t)
#define MV_MAGIC 213213213
#define MV_MMAP_THRESHOLD 4096 // WIP if size > 4096, use mmap()
#define MV_FREE_BIT(x) (x & 0x01)
#define MV_ALLOC_BIT(x) ((x >> 1) & 0x01)
```

For the moment, only the `malloc()` function is implemented:

```c
static void *mv_heap = NULL;
static mv_block_t *end_heap = NULL;
static mv_block_t *last_block = NULL;
static size_t last_size = 0;

static void *mv_search_block(size_t size)
{
    mv_block_t *block = NULL;
    if (last_block == NULL && last_size < size) {
        block = mv_heap;
    } else {
        block = last_block;
    }
    while (block != NULL) {
        if (block->size >= size && MV_FREE_BIT(block->state) == 0)
            break;
        block = block->next;
    }
    if (block != NULL) {
        if (mv_split_block(block, size) == 0) {
            end_heap = block->next;
        }
        block->state = 0x02;
    } else {
        if (sbrk(size) == (void *)-1)
            return (NULL);
        block = sbrk(0);
        block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
        block->prev = end_heap;
        block->size = size - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        block->state = 0x02;
        block->data = (unsigned char *)block + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        block->next = NULL;
        end_heap = block;
    }
    last_block = block;
    last_size = size;
    return (block->data);
}

static void *init_heap_sbrk(size_t size)
{
    mv_heap = sbrk(size);
    if (mv_heap == (void *)-1)
        return (NULL);
    mv_block_t *block = mv_heap;
    block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
    block->prev = NULL;
    block->size = size - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    block->state = 0x01;
    block->data = (unsigned char *)mv_heap + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    block->next = NULL;
    end_heap = block;
    return (block->data);
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        size = MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    else
        size = MV_ALIGN(size) + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    if (size >= PTRDIFF_MAX)
        return (NULL);
    if (mv_heap == NULL)
        return init_heap_sbrk(size);
    return (mv_search_block(size));
}
```

To manage memory fragmentation (merge / block release / split) :

```c
int mv_merge_block(mv_block_t *current)
{
    mv_block_t *prev = current->prev;
    mv_block_t *next = current->next;

    if (prev != NULL && MV_FREE_BIT(prev->state) == 0) {
        prev->size += current->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        prev->next = next;
        current = prev;
    }
    if (next != NULL && MV_FREE_BIT(next->state) == 0) {
        if (next->next != NULL) {
            current->size += next->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
            current->next = next->next;
        } else {
            current->next = NULL;
            if (sbrk(-(next->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)) == (void *)-1)
                return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int mv_suppress_block(mv_block_t *block)
{
    if (block == NULL)
        return (-1);
    if (MV_FREE_BIT(block->state) == 0 && block->next == NULL) {
        if (block->prev != NULL) {
            block->prev->next = NULL;
        }
        if (sbrk(-(block->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)) == (void *)-1)
            return (-1);
        return (0);
    }
    return (-1);
}

int mv_split_block(mv_block_t *block, size_t size)
{
    size_t new_block_size = block->size - size;
    mv_block_t *new_block = NULL;

    if (new_block_size < MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)
        return (-1);
    if (mv_suppress_block(block->next) == 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    new_block = (mv_block_t *)(unsigned char *)block + size;
    new_block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
    new_block->prev = block;
    new_block->size = new_block_size - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    new_block->state = 0x00;
    new_block->data = (unsigned char *)new_block + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    new_block->next = block->next;
    block->size = size;
    block->next = new_block;
    return (0);
}
```

To be able to view my blocks, I've coded functions that are supposed to display useful information:

```c
void mv_dump_block(mv_block_t *block)
{
    uint8_t usage_bit = block->state & 0x01;
    uint8_t allocation_method_bit = (block->state >> 1) & 0x01;

    printf("========================================\n");
    printf("Block : %p\n", (void *)block);
    printf("Magic : %d\n", block->magic);
    printf("Prev : %p\n", (void *)block->prev);
    printf("Size : %ld\n", block->size);
    printf("State of block : %s\n", (usage_bit == 0) ? "Available" : "Busy");
    printf("Allocation's type : %s\n", (allocation_method_bit == 0) ? "sbrk" : "mmap");
    printf("Data : %p\n", block->data);
    printf("Next : %p\n", (void *)block->next);
    printf("========================================\n");
}

void mv_dump_heap(void *ptr)
{
    mv_block_t *block = mv_get_block(ptr);

    while (block != NULL && block->prev != NULL)
        block = block->prev;
    while (block != NULL) {
        mv_dump_block(block);
        block = block->next;
    }
}

mv_block_t *mv_get_block(void *ptr)
{
    mv_block_t *block = (mv_block_t *)((unsigned char *)ptr - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE);

    if (block->magic != MV_MAGIC)
        return (NULL);
    return (block);
}
```

Here is my `main()` test function:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char *ptr = malloc(10);
    char *ptr2 = malloc(4096);
    mv_dump_heap(ptr);
    (void)ptr2;
    return (0);
}
```

And here's the gdb report:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555557f2 in mv_split_block (block=0x55555555a070, size=1072) at src/fragmentation.c:52
52          new_block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
```

For the moment, I'm compiling with GLIBC and the following flags: `-m64 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb3`

Can you help me solve this, I guess the `new_block` variable is misaligned during the split.

**UPDATE**

Since my test with `malloc(0)` is apparently disturbing in the comments, I've replaced it with 10 and the same result. For those of you who have misread, I have for the moment implemented ONLY `malloc()`.

I've also added my Makefile :

```
CC          =       gcc
CFLAGS      =       -m64 -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb3
LFLAGS      =       -I./include

SRC         =       $(shell find src/ -type f -name '*.c')
OBJ         =       $(SRC:.c=.o)

NAME        =       test/vlibc_malloc_test

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME) $(LFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    @rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: clean fclean re
```

**Reproducible code set**

The complete code is here : [Online GDB](https://onlinegdb.com/Zry5JbUnj)

Comment: Why do you `char *ptr = malloc(0);`? This isn't a pointer that you can dereference in `mv_dump_heap(ptr)` and there is no `realloc()` in the code.

Comment: Function `mv_dump_heap()` is not passing it to `free` but dereferences it. That function calls `mv_get_block()`, which subtracts something from the pointer, and then `if (block->magic != MV_MAGIC)` suggests you are trying to exploit  something.

Comment: Really? `mv_block_t *block = (mv_block_t *)((unsigned char *)ptr - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE);` followed by `if (block->magic != MV_MAGIC)` dereferences a pointer derived by arithmetic. It's UB.

Comment: @VirgilG. *As specified in the manual, malloc is supposed to handle a size of 0...* And [that value can be `NULL`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p1): "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."

Comment: *the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object* – let alone a different object.

Comment: How are you *using* your `malloc()` implementation in testing?  How are you compiling all your code?  How are you linking it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I invite you to reread my post.

Comment: Your `malloc(0)` is not disturbing.  You are having problems making your code work, and you made it more complex by returning non-NULL for `malloc( 0 );`

Comment: @AndrewHenle In the man I read precisely: "... if size is zero, malloc returns a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free()".

Passing `NULL` to `free()` will end in SIGABRT or some other error...

Comment: The C Standard is the ruling document for what `malloc()` can return.  The man page you read merely documents one implementation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ok from what I understand it's implementation defined. I'll see later if I return NULL or not. Can you help me with the question I asked in the post? Since when the size is 10 it doesn't work either.

Comment: "I guess" Don't. Use a debugger.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is a no-op and perfectly safe.

Comment: Please revise your question to be a [mre] not a bunch of snippets we have to self-assemble to see what is missing.

Comment: @AllanWind Done.

Comment: `MV_BLOCK_T_END_OFFSET` needs parentheses, but as it isn't used (at least in the code shown) it probably isn't the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may come from the incompatibility between your `malloc` function and the one from the C library: the `printf` function directly or indirectly uses `malloc` to allocate some memory for internal use and the blocks thus allocated are freed with `free`.  You replaced `malloc` so `printf` and/or the `FILE` handling functions use your `malloc` but the `free` function cannot handle the blocks allocated by your `malloc` function and this leads to undefined behavior and a segmentation fault.

You should use different names for your `malloc` clone and implement all the allocation functions: `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `aligned_alloc` `free`, `strdup`... and possibly some other ones, and test these thoroughly before you change the names to use the standard names.

Note also these remarks:

- **[major]**: in function `mv_split_block`, `new_block` is computed as `new_block = (mv_block_t *)(unsigned char *)block + size;`, which is incorrect. You should use:

  ```
  new_block = (mv_block_t *)((unsigned char *)block + size);
  ```
- **[major]**: you must parenthesize macro arguments in the definitions to avoid potential operator precedence problems at the expansion sites. For example:

  ```
  #define MV_BLOCK_T_END_OFFSET (MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE - sizeof(mv_block_t))
  #define MV_FREE_BIT(x) ((x) & 0x01)
  #define MV_ALLOC_BIT(x) (((x) >> 1) & 0x01)
  ```
- **[minor]**: the macro `MV_FREE_BIT` is error prone as it evaluates to `0` for available blocks and non zero for blocks in use. You should either change the bit value or change the macro name to `MV_BUSY_BIT`.
- **[minor]**: you should try and minimize the occurrence of padding in the header structure:

  ```
  typedef struct MV_BLOCK_S {
      uint32_t magic;
      uint32_t state; // First bit: 0 = block free, 1 = block used, second bit: 0 = sbrk() 1 = mmap()
      uint64_t size;
      struct MV_BLOCK_S *prev;
      void *data;
      struct MV_BLOCK_S *next;
  } mv_block_t;
  ```
- **[remark]**: there is actually no need for the `data` member as the data associated with the header is right after the structure, ie: `(void *)(block + 1)`.
- **[remark]**: the `size` member is also redundant except for the first and last blocks: you could use `(uint64_t)((unsigned char *)block->next - (unsigned char *)block->prev - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)`.
- **[minor]**: in `mv_split_block`, in case `if (new_block_size < MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)` you should return `0` as the block is not large enough to be split but large enough to accommodate the allocation request.
- **[remark]**: function `mv_dump_heap` should not need an argument: it should dump the heap pointed to by global variable `mv_heap`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rather long to track, but right before the assignment that causes SIGSEGV, you have bad casting. The line:

`new_block = (mv_block_t *)(unsigned char *)block + size;`

Should be:

`new_block = (mv_block_t *)((unsigned char *)block + size);`

Otherwise the addition to the block pointer is not `size` bytes but `size * sizeof(mv_block_t)` bytes

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `mv_search_block`.

You are doing:

```
if (sbrk(size) == (void *) -1)
    return (NULL);
block = sbrk(0);
```

This is reversed. It should be:

```
block = sbrk(0);
if (sbrk(size) == (void *) -1)
    return (NULL);
```

Remember that the "program break point" (returned by `sbrk`), for intents and purposes, is the address of the *end* of the (current) heap area.

In the original code:

1. Increase program break point
2. Get current break point
3. `block` is pointing *past* the end of the allocated area

In the modified code:

1. Get current break point
2. Increase the heap space
3. `block` is now pointing to the end of the heap - size

---

In order to find this, I had to create a buildable version of your code. I added debug `printf` as `dbgprt`.

Note that, without some care, calling `printf` can cause `printf` to call `malloc` and it can be *your* `malloc`. This can produce infinite recursion.

To avoid this, in `dbgprt`, I used `sprintf` and `write` as `sprintf` doesn't use `malloc` (under `glibc` at least).

I did a fair amount of refactoring. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>

// Here's the block metadata structure:
typedef struct MV_BLOCK_S {
    uint32_t magic;
    struct MV_BLOCK_S *prev;
    uint64_t size;

    // First bit:
    // 0 = block free
    // 1 = block used
    // second bit:
    // 0 = sbrk()
    // 1 = mmap()
    uint8_t state;

    void *data;
    struct MV_BLOCK_S *next;
} mv_block_t;

// Some of the macros I use:
#define MV_ALIGN(x) (((((x) - 1) >> 3) << 3) + 8)
#define MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE  MV_ALIGN(sizeof(mv_block_t))
#define MV_BLOCK_T_END_OFFSET MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE - sizeof(mv_block_t)
#define MV_MAGIC 213213213
#define MV_MMAP_THRESHOLD 4096          // WIP if size > 4096, use mmap()
#define MV_FREE_BIT(x) (x & 0x01)
#define MV_ALLOC_BIT(x) ((x >> 1) & 0x01)

//For the moment, only the `malloc()` function is implemented:
static void *mv_heap = NULL;
static mv_block_t *end_heap = NULL;
static mv_block_t *last_block = NULL;
static size_t last_size = 0;

int mv_split_block(mv_block_t *block, size_t size);
mv_block_t *mv_get_block(void *ptr);

#define dbgprtattr(_lvl) \
    __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,_lvl,_lvl + 1)))

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    _dbgprt(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#if DEBUG
#define xbrk(_siz) \
    _xbrk(_siz,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)
#else
#define xbrk(_siz) \
    sbrk(_siz)
#endif

#define xalloc  malloc

void dbgprtattr(1)
_dbgprt(const char *fmt,...)
{
    int sverr = errno;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap,fmt);
#if 0
    vprintf(fmt,ap);
#else
    char buf[1000];
    ssize_t len = vsprintf(buf,fmt,ap);
    write(1,buf,len);
#endif
    va_end(ap);

    errno = sverr;
}

#define PP_FMT      "%8.8zX"

void *pp_base;
void *pp_last;

char *
tlsbuf(void)
{
    static int bufidx = 0;
    static char bufpool[16][1024];

    char *buf = bufpool[bufidx];
    bufidx = (bufidx + 1) % 16;

    *buf = 0;

    return buf;
}

const char *
PP_PRT(const void *ptr)
{
    int sverr = errno;
    char *buf = tlsbuf();
    ssize_t dif;

    do {
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            sprintf(buf,"NULLNULL");
            break;
        }

        dif = ptr - pp_base;

        if (dif < 0)
            sprintf(buf,"-%8.8zX",-dif);
        else
            sprintf(buf,"%8.8zX",dif);
    } while (0);

    errno = sverr;

    return buf;
}

const char *
SZ_PRT(size_t size)
{
    int sverr = errno;
    char *buf = tlsbuf();

    sprintf(buf,"%8.8zX",size);

    errno = sverr;

    return buf;
}

void *
_xbrk(size_t siz,const char *fnc,int lno)
{
    void *ptr;

    dbgprt("_xbrk: ENTER siz=%s fnc='%s' lno=%d pp_last=%s\n",
        SZ_PRT(siz),fnc,lno,PP_PRT(pp_last));

    ptr = sbrk(siz);

    pp_last = ptr;
    if (pp_base == NULL)
        pp_base = ptr;

    dbgprt("_xbrk: EXIT ptr=%s\n",PP_PRT(ptr));

    return ptr;
}

static void *
mv_search_block(size_t size)
{
    mv_block_t *block = NULL;

    dbgprt("mv_search_block: ENTER size=%s last_block=%s last_size=%s\n",
        SZ_PRT(size),PP_PRT(last_block),SZ_PRT(last_size));

    if (last_block == NULL && last_size < size) {
        block = mv_heap;
    }
    else {
        block = last_block;
    }

    while (block != NULL) {
        if (block->size >= size && MV_FREE_BIT(block->state) == 0)
            break;
        block = block->next;
    }

    do {
        if (block != NULL) {
            if (mv_split_block(block, size) == 0) {
                end_heap = block->next;
                dbgprt("mv_search_block: SETEND end_heap=%s\n",
                    PP_PRT(end_heap));
            }
            block->state = 0x02;
            break;
        }

//#if SHOWBUG
#if 1
        if (xbrk(size) == (void *) -1)
            return (NULL);
        block = xbrk(0);
#else
        block = xbrk(0);
        if (xbrk(size) == (void *) -1)
            return (NULL);
#endif

        dbgprt("mv_search_block: NEWBLOCK block=%s\n",PP_PRT(block));

        block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
        block->prev = end_heap;
        block->size = size - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        block->state = 0x02;
        block->data = (unsigned char *) block + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        block->next = NULL;

        end_heap = block;
    } while (0);

    last_block = block;
    last_size = size;

    dbgprt("mv_search_block: EXIT block=%s\n",PP_PRT(block));

    return (block->data);
}

static void *
init_heap_sbrk(size_t size)
{
    void *ret = NULL;

    dbgprt("init_heap_sbrk: ENTER size=%s\n",SZ_PRT(size));

    do {
        mv_heap = xbrk(size);
        if (mv_heap == (void *) -1)
            break;

        mv_block_t *block = mv_heap;

        block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
        block->prev = NULL;
        block->size = size - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        block->state = 0x01;
        block->data = (unsigned char *) mv_heap + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        block->next = NULL;

        end_heap = block;

        ret = block->data;
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("init_heap_sbrk: EXIT ret=%s\n",PP_PRT(ret));

    return ret;
}

void *
xalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr = NULL;

    dbgprt("xalloc: ENTER size=%s\n",SZ_PRT(size));

    if (size == 0)
        size = MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
    else
        size = MV_ALIGN(size) + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;

    do {
        if (size >= PTRDIFF_MAX)
            break;

        if (mv_heap == NULL)
            ptr = init_heap_sbrk(size);
        else
            ptr = mv_search_block(size);
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("xalloc: EXIT ptr=%s\n",PP_PRT(ptr));

    return ptr;
}

// To manage memory fragmentation (merge / block release / split) :
int
mv_merge_block(mv_block_t *current)
{
    mv_block_t *prev = current->prev;
    mv_block_t *next = current->next;

    if (prev != NULL && MV_FREE_BIT(prev->state) == 0) {
        prev->size += current->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        prev->next = next;
        current = prev;
    }
    if (next != NULL && MV_FREE_BIT(next->state) == 0) {
        if (next->next != NULL) {
            current->size += next->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
            current->next = next->next;
        }
        else {
            current->next = NULL;
            if (xbrk(-(next->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)) == (void *) -1)
                return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}

int
mv_suppress_block(mv_block_t *block)
{
    int ret = -1;

    dbgprt("my_suppress_block: ENTER block=%s\n",PP_PRT(block));

    do {
        if (block == NULL)
            break;

        if (MV_FREE_BIT(block->state) == 0 && block->next == NULL) {
            if (block->prev != NULL) {
                block->prev->next = NULL;
            }
            if (xbrk(-(block->size + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)) == (void *) -1)
                break;
            ret = 0;
        }
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("mv_suppress_block: EXIT ret=%d\n",ret);

    return ret;
}

int
mv_split_block(mv_block_t *block, size_t size)
{
    size_t new_block_size = block->size - size;
    mv_block_t *new_block = NULL;
    int ret = -1;

    dbgprt("mv_split_block: ENTER block=%s size=%s\n",
        PP_PRT(block),SZ_PRT(size));

    do {
        if (new_block_size < MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE)
            break;

        if (mv_suppress_block(block->next) == 0)
            break;

        new_block = (mv_block_t *) (unsigned char *) block + size;
        new_block->magic = MV_MAGIC;
        new_block->prev = block;
        new_block->size = new_block_size - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        new_block->state = 0x00;
        new_block->data = (unsigned char *) new_block + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE;
        new_block->next = block->next;

        block->size = size;
        block->next = new_block;

        ret = 0;
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("mv_split_block: EXIT ret=%d\n",ret);

    return ret;
}

// To be able to view my blocks, I've coded functions that are supposed to
// display useful information:
void
mv_dump_block(mv_block_t *block)
{
    uint8_t usage_bit = block->state & 0x01;
    uint8_t allocation_method_bit = (block->state >> 1) & 0x01;

    _dbgprt("========================================\n");
    _dbgprt("Block : %s\n", PP_PRT(block));
    _dbgprt("Magic : %d\n", block->magic);
    _dbgprt("Prev : %s\n", PP_PRT(block->prev));
    _dbgprt("Size : %ld\n", block->size);
    _dbgprt("State of block : %s\n", (usage_bit == 0) ? "Available" : "Busy");
    _dbgprt("Allocation's type : %s\n", (allocation_method_bit == 0) ? "sbrk" : "mmap");
    _dbgprt("Data : %s\n", PP_PRT(block->data));
    _dbgprt("Next : %s\n", PP_PRT(block->next));
    _dbgprt("========================================\n");
}

void
mv_dump_heap(void *ptr)
{
    mv_block_t *block = mv_get_block(ptr);

    while (block != NULL && block->prev != NULL)
        block = block->prev;
    while (block != NULL) {
        mv_dump_block(block);
        block = block->next;
    }
}

mv_block_t *
mv_get_block(void *ptr)
{
    mv_block_t *block = (mv_block_t *) ((unsigned char *) ptr - MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE);

    if (block->magic != MV_MAGIC)
        return (NULL);
    return (block);
}

// Here is my `main()` test function:
int
main(void)
{
#if 1
    pp_base = sbrk(0);
    pp_last = pp_base;
#endif

    dbgprt("main: BLOCKSIZE %s %s %s\n",
        SZ_PRT(sizeof(mv_block_t)),
        SZ_PRT(MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE),
        SZ_PRT(MV_ALIGN(0) + MV_BLOCK_T_SIZE));

    char *ptr = xalloc(10);
    char *ptr2 = xalloc(4096);

    mv_dump_heap(ptr);
    (void) ptr2;
    return (0);
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`